# How to load test an HTTP endpoint with FSharp Interactive

Tags: azure, f#, azure-functions, f#-interactive

What is the best what to load test a http endpoint from the FSharp interactive? For example I tried to load a `HelloWorld` Azure Function with the following:

```
open FSharp.Data
async { 
    let url = "https://transactive.azurewebsites.net/api/HelloWorld"
    for i = 1 to 1000 do
        let! html = Http.AsyncRequestString(url)
        printfn "Invokation %i" i  } |> Async.Start
```

Afer running this in the FSharp Interactive the AzureFunctions Live Log shows 12 TPS. Starting a second FSI results in 24 TPS. Doing this instead:

```
open FSharp.Data
let makeAsync = async { 
    let url = "https://transactive.azurewebsites.net/api/HelloWorld"
    for i = 1 to 1000 do
        let! html = Http.AsyncRequestString(url)
        printfn "Invokation %i" i  }


let a = [| for i in 1..5-> makeAsync |]
let results = a |> Async.Parallel |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Results in 60TPS in the Azure Live Log (image). Interestingly up to a maximum of 5, every increase in the parallelism resulted in another 12TPS. Increasing the parallelism beyond 5 did not increase TPS. However starting a second FSI results in about 120TPS.

[image: Azure Function Live Log]

I have two questions:

1. What is going on? Why is 12 a magic number?
2. What is the best way to drive a HTTP endpoint as hard as possible from a script running in a single FSI?

My machine is a VM with 4 cores allocated and 10Gig RAM.

In case someone wants to try things the function is still running (assuming it has not run into the `Daily Usage` Quota).